# Using mail servers in Java

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, mail-server

I want to use a mail server where the users send emails to it and then I parse this emails then do some action.

Please suggest me what mail server to be used  and where to start.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the easiest way for a Java application to receive incoming email?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561011/what-is-the-easiest-way-for-a-java-application-to-receive-incoming-email)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Apache James](http://james.apache.org/) is a mail server written in Java that you could use.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use JavaMail API to read a POP3/IMAP mailbox on your regular mail server. This makes it easier to use a mailbox in your regular domain. Camel packages these API's at a high level and makes it really easy to integrate with mailboxes, transform the message inside and send the results wherever they are needed.

Now if it are easy things you need to do then you can configure most mailservers to deliver mails to a script. This is REALLY easy but Java is not really suitable to write this script in  because the startup cost of the JVM is too high. A simple batch script or perl/ruby/vbscript thingy could be all you need.

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying you want to use Java to send a mail message to a mailbox configured on your mail server or to read from the mailbox and to process the message? So you just want to know of a mail server you can install on your local pc to test with? If that's the case and you are running on a Windows OS you can install [hMailServer](http://www.hmailserver.com/). If you are using Linux / Unix you can configure [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/).